# PowerMockito.verifyStatic() with arguments usage explanation

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermockito

I am studying the following example that uses `PowerMockito` framework:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Static.class)
public class YourTestCase {
    @Test
    public void testMethodThatCallsStaticMethod() {
        // mock all the static methods in a class called "Static"
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Static.class);
        // use Mockito to set up your expectation
        Mockito.when(Static.firstStaticMethod(param)).thenReturn(value);
        Mockito.when(Static.secondStaticMethod()).thenReturn(123);

        // execute your test
        classCallStaticMethodObj.execute();

        // Different from Mockito, always use PowerMockito.verifyStatic() first
        // to start verifying behavior
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(2));
        // IMPORTANT:  Call the static method you want to verify
        Static.firstStaticMethod(param);


        // IMPORTANT: You need to call verifyStatic() per method verification, 
        // so call verifyStatic() again
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(); // default times is once
        // Again call the static method which is being verified 
        Static.secondStaticMethod();

        // Again, remember to call verifyStatic()
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.never());
        // And again call the static method. 
        Static.thirdStaticMethod();
    }
}
```

I am trying to figure out what kind of behaviour the code is checking in the following "coupled" lines:

```
    ............        

    PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(2));
    Static.firstStaticMethod(param);

    ..................

    PowerMockito.verifyStatic(); // default times is once
    Static.secondStaticMethod();

    ..................

    PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.never());
    Static.thirdStaticMethod();
```

what is exactly checking in each pair? E.g.: the first pair checks that exactly two static methods are called from the prepared class?

Comment: Johan, did you ever find an answer to your question? If yes it would be great if you answered it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(2));
Static.firstStaticMethod(param);
```

means **Static.firstStaticMethod** was called twice.